# I want to add elements in a particular column of Excel one by one using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am able to write the function but I get a memory error.

I want to get the data of `i` in a column `name` (bolded below in code)

Suppose there is a column of date time with format '%Y-%M-%D %H:%m:%s' and I have another column with price changing every second , then I need to make two new columns where 1st will carry the average of price for last 1 min, and while 2nd will carry the average of price for last ten minutes, where these two column will fill perfectly according to time, like if suppose we start at 10 :10:01 and ends at 10:11:00 then we add same average value of last one min in all rows between this one minute period , same with 2nd one where "x" is a list of 12000 elements

```
m = list(set(x))
    f1 = [0,0,]
    f10 = [0,0,]
    index = []
    index10 = []

    for i in m:
        index.append(x.index(i))
    
    for i in index[0:len(index):9]:
        index10.append(i)
```

For differnce if equal to 1 in x

```
    total = 0
    for i in index[2:len(index)-1]:
        j = i+1
        list = df['Price'][i:j]
        for i in list:
            total = (total+i)/j
    
        f1.append(total)
        total = 0
    
    for i in f1[0:len(m)]:
        j = i+1
        for l in range(0,j):
            **df['Average last 1 min'][l] = i**
```

for differnce if equal to 10 in x

```
    total1 = 0
    for i in index10[2:len(index10)-1]:
        j = i+1
        list = df['Price'][i:j]
        for i in list:
            total1 = (total1+i)/j
        f1.append(total1)
        total1 = 0
    
    for i in f10[0:len(m)]:
        j = i+1
        for l in range(0,j):
            
            **df['Average last 10 min'][l] = i**
    
    df.to_excel('A:\\Test\\time.xlsx')
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you update your question and add some example output? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure  suppose There is a column of date time with format '%Y-%M-%D %H:%m:%s' 
and I have another column with price changing every second , then I need to make two new columns where 1st will carry the average of price for last 1 min, and while 2nd will carry the average of price for last ten minutes , 

where these two column will fill perfectly according to time , like if suppose we start at 10 :10:01 and ends at 10:11:00  then we add same average value of last one min in all rows between this one minute period  , 
same with 2nd one